# What symbol to use for a electronic circuit breaker in a schematic?

Tags: symbol, circuit-breaker

What symbol should I use to [electronic circuit breaker](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2909902&library=usen&pcck=P-17-01-05-03-01&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL) in a schematic?

Comment: [Circuit breaker symbols](https://www.google.com/search?q=circuit+breaker+symbol&safe=strict&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-0aangsHlAhVHfMAKHWWrB0YQ_AUIEigB&biw=1479&bih=920).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is clearly a lack of research and google yields hundreds of answers.

Answer (score 2):

depends on the target for the schematic, I mean where I learned protection circuits we draw a box.

You can follow ANSI standard e.g. [ANSI Y32.2-1975](https://web.archive.org/web/20201208201223/https://www.noao.edu/ets/Mechanical/Policies/ANSI%20Y32.2-1975.pdf).

here are some examples of schematics too

https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1025/ML102530301.pdf e.g. page 5,

[image]

thing is depending on the country/target audience they might use a different symbol so I think you need to do research about how it works where you live.